# What is the least invasive way to compile Groovy unit test code with Maven

Tags: maven, groovy

I have an existing Java project built with Maven.  I want to write some Groovy classes for unit testing.  What is the least invasive way to get Maven to compile those classes?

Current versions of GMaven do not support Groovy compilation, and I don't want to use the groovy-eclipse-compiler for the existing Java code.  What is the simplest way to get the Groovy code compiled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some options:

- Use an older version of GMaven
- Use the new [GMavenPlus](https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus) (not sure if it has been released already as I can't reach GitHub at the moment)
- Use the `groovyc` Ant task

Comment: Thanks.  The last option is pretty appealing.  Is there an example somewhere?

Comment: You mean how to use it from Maven? I'm not aware of any.

Comment: I think maven-antrun-plugin would be what you want.